# How to debug external .cpp files on Eclipse CDT ( C++ )

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have big project in directory "project". I build this project using cmake into another directory "build". For coding I try to use Eclipse, but when I try to import my code into Eclipse ( File->Import->C/C++->Existing Code as Makefile Project ), of course I can import only "build" directory without "project" ( because make file are in "build" and "project" is empty for Eclipse ).

When I run my build in debug mode, I can debug only binary data, because debuger can't seen sources in "project" directory. How I can setup debuger for use sources from "project" directory? Thanks if some one answered!

Answer (score 0):

import your Project (rootdir not build) as MakeFile Project into the Workspace (select GNU Toolschain or Linux GCC). Now open your project properties -> c++ build and select the build folder inside your project.

Now you can compile it and create a new run configuration for debugging.

Greez ZuSe

Edit:

I assume your rootfolder looks like this

cmake/

CmakeList.txt

src/

dep/

../

now you create a folder build
you switch to build and run cmake cmake ../ -flags  (no eclipse-project, use default gcc)

After you have done this u can import your rootfolder to eclipse cdt and select root/build as build folder.  Where is the problem? Eclipse CDT only wants to now where the makefile is at buildtime (thats why you manually need to select the buildfolder)

Comment: I can't import rootdir as MakeFile project because rootdir doesn't has make file. It has only cmake file! And cmake file create make files when building. I know I can proceed cmake build into root directory and problem will be automatically solved, but my goal is create external build from cmake.

Comment: Move directories it's not a solution for some reasons. I need just known how to setup Eclipse for current directories ( out-of-source build ).

Comment: Same thing? You can also configure build directories outside your workspace.. same function

Comment: Nothing work, dgb in Eclipse seen sources but not symbols. Build 100% with debug symbols. First problem solved, Eclipse already can see sources! I do what you say but didn't work. Problem was in the same directory for eclipse workspace and project workspace. That's must be two different workspaces. But what can be wrong with the debug symbols?

Comment: xmash it don't understand your problem. I will provide some screenshots for you, how i do it

Answer (score 0):

You do not need sources in your workspace to debug the application if you built the application on your system - build directory & paths are in your executable debug information.

1. Make sure you pass -g both to the compiler and linker.
2. Try command-line GDB - it should find sources as well.
3. You may setup custom source mapping in the Eclipse CDT debugger when setting up the launch configuration - but I believe this is mostly for cases when sources were moved after you built the application or if you built on another system.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i do it, step by step. It is a simple cmake project i downloaded from github.
Works like a harm.[image: imagebam.com]
 [image: imagebam.com]
 [image: imagebam.com]
 [imagebam.com http://thumbnails101.imagebam.com/23645/1e5c42236445850.jpg](http://thumbnails101.imagebam.com/23645/1e5c42236445850.jpg) [image: imagebam.com]
 [image: imagebam.com]
 [image: imagebam.com]
 [imagebam.com http://thumbnails101.imagebam.com/23645/64cb47236445860.jpg](http://thumbnails101.imagebam.com/23645/64cb47236445860.jpg) [image: imagebam.com]

Comment: I do all what you shown. And have this for breakpoints: "No symbol table is loaded. Use the "file" command." - in Eclipse console. :) I have no time to fix this problem so I use manually debug, deadline is closely. :) I think something happens with gdb. Well, when I'll finish this project, I'll try to solve this problem just for interesting and give comment here. Everybody thanks for help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you put better photo?? I cannot see anything.